# Chef cannot get httpd depend

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, recipe

I am learning chef at the moment using OpsWorks , currently I am trying to create a recipe that will install 2 package in one instance. I stored my cookbook on github.. there I have a recipe that is like this - webserver.rb

```
# Install apache and start the service
httpd_service 'site' do 
  mpm 'prefork'
  action [:create, :start]
end

# Add the site configuration
httpd_config 'site' do
  instance 'site'
  source 'site.conf.erb'
  notifies :restart, 'httpd_service[site]'
end

#create the document root directory
#directory '/var/www/public_html' do
#  recursive true
#end

#write the homepage
file '/var/www/index.html' do 
  content '<html>This is a web</html>'
  mode '0644'
  owner 'web_admin'
  group 'web_admin'
end

# Install apache , config and etc END

# Install the mod_php5 apache module
httpd_module 'php' do 
  instance 'site'
end

#install php5-mysql
package 'php-mysql' do 
  action :install
  notifies :restart, 'httpd_service[site]'
end

#write the homepage
file '/var/www/index2.php' do 
  content '<html><?php echo phpinfo(); ?></html>'
  mode '0644'
  owner 'web_admin'
  group 'web_admin'
end
```

I am following the tutorial in AWS creating a LAMP environment. Unfortunately when I run this to my Instance , opsworks_cookbook_demo::default (it will run some include , including webserver.) am getting error that `precondition httpd cookbook not found`, I already added on my metadaba.rb depends 'httpd' '~> ..' ,Can someone guide me what the wrong doing here. Coz I assume whenever you put depends 'httpd' it will extend my cookbook to use that cookbook.

Do I need berkshelf for this case? (Currently I am using AWS OpsWorks and have my recipe in github)

Answer (score 3):

You have to download all the dependencies ahead of time to feed to OpsWorks. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/best-practices-packaging-cookbooks-locally.html for more info. The older Chef 11 stacks used to somewhat automate this for you by running `berks vendor` on the target, but now you need to do that yourself on your workstation.